# Use only one build directory for every module in gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle

## Original question

I'm trying to solve `NoClassDefFoundError` on project with several modules.
First, we have a shared module (here named `common`). It is used (as dependency) in every other module with `settings.gradle` file :

```
includeBuild '../common'
```

And on `build.gradle` file, block `dependencies`

```
implementation "org.example:common:1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

All others modules are spring boot application.
The problème I have is that when running `module1` for example, then running `module2`, I get randomly `NoClassDefFoundError` when using `module1` (calling rest route).

Thing is, I didn't succeed to reproduce the behaviour with a simple project.
The first thing I think of is the build folder on `common` module. Indeed, when building `module1` and then `module2`, I think build directory of `common` is erased then recreate and it causes `NoClassDefFoundError` on `module1`.

That's why I'm trying to change the build directory of `common` module.

So, finally, I want to change build directory of `common` like:

- in `module1` build folder running build of `module1`
- in `module2` build folder running build of `module2`
- etc...

I know I can change the build directory with `buildDir` attribute, but I don't know how to change it dynamically.

## UPDATE May 18

More information about my project.
Each module is already a gradle multiproject

I've tried to configure a multiproject on the top of all multiprojects like:

```
- back
  - module1
    - module1-submodule1
    - module1-submodule2
  - module2
    - module2-submodule1
    - module2-submodule2
  - common
    - common-submodule1
    - common-submodule2
```

I get it work after some time. It is not obvious and many of our build commands (continuous integration for example) have to be re-write.
But I still get `NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

I realy think it is a build directory configuration problem.

Comment: maybe a multiproject build setup would be more adapted to your need?  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html  . common, module1 & moduleX would be sub-projects with inter-subproject dependences

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried it, but I still get the same errors